# Removing duplicate URLs by adding to set?

Tags: python, web-scraping, duplicates

So I'm trying to write a webscraper to collect absolute links to other pages in python 3 (in this example from https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html). To remove the duplicates I collect, I've been adding them to a set. This seems to work for most of the links, but a few are only being added to the set as '/', so I'm missing a few links, plus I'm getting a junk entry of '/'.

Comment: Is `finallink = finallink[-1]` supposed to be `finallink = finallink[:-1]`?

Comment: Oh man... do I feel like an idiot. That looks like it worked! Thank you!!!

Comment: Also check out `urllib.parse` (standard Python library) which may have some useful functions for you to parse and combine URLs.

Comment: Will do. Thank you!